# Generate class diagram for IPhone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, class-diagram

I am trying to find a good tool for iphone/objective-C to generate class diagram to code. I want it to be flexible to change and modify the diagram so that I can separate that diagram to many smaller ones.

That means, I can show some parts of the viewcontroller interacting with model classes. It will be easier to understand and get changes.

I tried with XCode:

It is not easy to draw some lines ourselves to accomodate the part XCode can not generate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XCode V4 has class diagram functionality, unfortunately it's not available for download yet for general developers.

Comment: yeah, I am really waiting for XCode v4 for a lot of functionalities

Comment: The current XCode also has the class diagram functionality but the problems is that it is really bad. Is the next XCode better for this?

Comment: Anyone know when it's available for download ?

Comment: I think we will have to wait for some time. I am not sure, but it will not be released soon

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode Version 4.*, this functionality has been removed.

Hope this helps.